# Find index of item in a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, vb.net, multidimensional-array

If I have a multidimensional array:

```
Dim test(,,) As String
```

How can I loop through the array to find if another variable is contained in the second dimension of the array?

Obviously, this won’t work:

```
Dim x As Integer = test.IndexOf(otherVariable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried LINQ?  Perhaps something along the lines of (pseudo-code-ish):

```
var x = (from item in test
         where item.IndexOf(OtherVariable) >= 0 
         select item.IndexOf(OtherVariable)).SingleOrDefault();
```

FYI, this should work if you declare your array like this instead:

```
string[][] test
```

Comment: It's multidimensional so the Contains won't work since item itself is an array

Comment: Ok, then substitute Contains for array-friendly code (like I said, pseudo-code-ish).  Instead of Contains, how about where item.IndexOf(OtherVariable) >= 0 ?  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to loop through the array using the [Array.GetLowerBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlowerbound.aspx) and [Array.GetUpperBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound.aspx) methods. The `Array.IndexOf` and `Array.FindIndex` methods don't support multidimensional arrays.

For example:

```
string[,,] data = new string[3,3,3];
data.SetValue("foo", 0, 1, 2 );

for (int i = data.GetLowerBound(0); i <= data.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    for (int j = data.GetLowerBound(1); j <= data.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        for (int k = data.GetLowerBound(2); k <= data.GetUpperBound(2); k++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}: {3}", i, j, k, data[i,j,k]);
```

You might also find the [Array.GetLength method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) and [Array.Rank property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.rank.aspx) useful. I recommend setting up a small multidimensional array and using all these methods and properties to get an idea of how they work.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do something similar to this..

```
Dim test As String(,) = New String(,) {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5", "6"}}

Dim cols As Integer = test.GetUpperBound(0)
Dim rows As Integer = test.GetUpperBound(1)

Dim toFind As String = "4"
Dim xIndex As Integer
Dim yIndex As Integer

For x As Integer = 0 To cols - 1
    For y As Integer = 0 To rows - 1
        If test(x, y) = toFind Then
            xIndex = x
            yIndex = y
        End If
    Next
Next
```

On a side note, a lot of people don't realise that you can use a for each loop on multi-dimension arrays.

```
For Each value As String In test
    Console.WriteLine(value)
Next
```

This will progressively loop through all dimensions of an array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the previous question you asked

```
For i = 0 To i = test.Count - 1
   If set(1).Equals(someVariable) Then
      x = i
      Exit For
   End If
Next
```