# Is it possible to get the "coordinates" of an element based on it's index?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a string[5,5] array. Is it possible to calculate the position of an element based om it's index, assuming this will always be a 5x5 matrix?

By position I mean the element's cartesian 'coordinates' in the given array.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327805/find-index-of-item-in-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: @NathanAldenSr that is not a duplicate

Comment: You're right. I should say that the *answers* directly answer this question. The question itself is slightly different. OP should check out the answers in that other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a simple extension method would help:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void FindCoordinates<T>(this T[,] source, int index, out int x,out int y)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < source.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                counter++;
                if (counter == index)
                {
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        x = -1;
        y = -1;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int[,] array = new int[5,5];

int x, y;
array.FindCoordinates(5,out x,out y);
Console.WriteLine("x = {0} y = {1}", x, y);  // x = 0 y = 4

array.FindCoordinates(7,out x,out y);
Console.WriteLine("x = {0} y = {1}", x, y); // x = 1 y = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer - Yes

Detailed Answer - 
"Single dimensional and jagged array elements are directly accessed or modified from the memory location of the instance of the runtime array type based on their index. For this CLR provides a special IL instruction named ldelem and stelem, which retrieves and modifies an array element based on its index and the array Object Reference available on the stack. Whereas the multidimensional array elements are accessed or modified using method calls on the synthesized runtime type of the array type. This makes jagged arrays much faster than the multidimensional arrays and is recommended way of using arrays in case multiple dimensions are required. Jagged arrays are CLS compliant and are mistakenly documented as NOT CLS compliant. This fact is acknowledged in MSDN2."

Copied from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/net_type_internals.aspx?fid=459323&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2567811